# How to use google profile picture in another android application without google login?

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-authenticator

How to use google profile picture in another android application without google login?
I want, when user install my application and open it, then automatic show his/her google profile picture. Then click his/her picture and login with his/her google account. how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm expecting that you can't (or at least shouldn't) be trying to get the profile image from another app for a Google account. One thing to consider is that if there are multiple users on the same device how can you know which picture is the correct one?

The documentation for Google sign-in shows step-by-step how to add it in:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Which starts with a Google sign-in button

[image: Google sign in button]

followed by an account chooser which will have the user's profile picture for each account available on the device, and allows the user to enter a new account not even registered on that device.

[image]